# Unable to insert data in arabic form in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried each and every possible solution on the Internet and this forum but nothing seems to be working.

using after `mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);`

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

after that i include code in every php file  :

```
<?php

 mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

?>
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Also I just noticed you're mixing `mysqli` and `mysql_query` so none of this has any hope of working.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `mysql_*` functions, if you are going to create connection using `mysqli_*`. Here you can use `mysqli_set_charset()`

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your database collation is `utf8_general_ci`
2. After connection..

   mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8;");

   mysql_query("SET CHARACTER_SET utf8;");